# Display based on dynamic select dropdown in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a dynamic select but I don't know how to display the selected values on the view. I'm struggling because apparently I can't create a click event on the option and I don't know how to access the option via the click event on  tag.

Here's the html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<hr>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <form [formGroup]="catSelection">
      <select 
      formControlName="transactionControl" 
      (change)="onDisplayCategory()">
    <option  [ngValue]="transactionCategory" *ngFor="let transactionCategory of transactionCategories">{{transactionCategory}}</option>
    </select>
    </form>
  </div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

Here's the ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataFetchingService } from '../shared/data-fetching.service';
import { Transaction } from '../shared/transaction.model';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-transactions',
  templateUrl: './transactions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./transactions.component.css']
})
export class TransactionsComponent implements OnInit {
  result: Transaction[]
  transactions: Transaction[]
  transactionCategories: Set<string>
  catSelection: FormGroup;

  constructor(private dfService: DataFetchingService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.catSelection = new FormGroup({
      'transactionControl': new FormControl(null)})
    this.loadPosts()
  }

  loadPosts() {
    this.dfService.fetchData().subscribe(
      posts=>{
        this.transactions=posts;
        this.transactionCategories = new Set<string>(posts.map(p => p.category))
        console.log(this.transactionCategories)
        console.log(this.transactions)
      }
    )
  }

  onDisplayCategory() {
    console.log("change works")
  }
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6ni1pg

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angular's two-way binding for this.

Use `[(ngModel)]="selectedCategory"` on your `select` and then use `selectedCategory` in your **ts** file as a variable and you will have access to the option chosen. Then use your variable when an option is selected.

```
onDisplayCategory() {
  console.log("change works");
  console.log(this.selectedCategory)
}
```

I've modified your example, have a look:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yx9jhq

Answer (score 1):

you can get your selected dropdown values as below one.

`onDisplayCategory() {
    console.log("change works");
    console.log(this.catSelection.value.transactionControl);
  }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use **@Input** and **@Ouput** to submit the selected value in the dropdown (in child *transactions-edit.component.ts*) and show it (in parent *transactions.component.ts*).

To do this, you would probably modify a little bit in your codes

Changes in *transactions.component.html*

```
<app-transactions-edit (createPostEvent)="onPostCreated($event)"></app-transactions-edit> <!-- change this line-->
<hr>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <form [formGroup]="catSelection">
      <select 
        formControlName="transactionControl" 
        (change)="onDisplayCategory()">
    <option [ngValue]="transactionCategory" *ngFor="let transactionCategory of transactionCategories">{{transactionCategory}}</option>
    </select>
    </form>
  </div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

Add one more method in *transactions.component.ts*

```
onPostCreated(postData: Transaction) {
    console.log("onPostCreated", postData)
    this.catSelection.controls['transactionControl'].patchValue(postData.category)
}
```

Changes in *transactions-edit.component.ts*

```
import { Component, Input, Output, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { DataStorageService } from '../../shared/data-storage.service';
import { Transaction } from '../../shared/transaction.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-transactions-edit',
  templateUrl: './transactions-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./transactions-edit.component.css']
})
export class TransactionsEditComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() createPostEvent = new EventEmitter()

  constructor(private dsService: DataStorageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onCreatePost(postData: Transaction) {
    this.dsService
      .createAndStorePost(postData.name, postData.amount, postData.category)
      .subscribe(responseData => {
        console.log(postData)
        this.createPostEvent.emit(postData)
      })

  }
}
```

See the source at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y3w7yv

Comment: Hey! Your example works fine on changing the value of the select. Which is super cool by the way. But my intention was to display the list based on the category chosen on select. Sorry if I wasn't clear. :)

Comment: Do you want to filter out the list of posts in https://budget-dfc78.firebaseio.com/posts.json where the category == selected category in the form?

Comment: Yes. The posts above told me how to grab the value of select. I also know how to filter the list "manually", just creating one array for each category. But if I have 1000 categories I need an elegant approach just filtering based on value of select.

Comment: I updated the code, can you check it out. Hope this helps you.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y3w7yv

Comment: It is nice to get feedback from you @Pablo Aguirre de Souza if the latest update that satisfies you. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I was away. Your solution works, but slightly different from what I intended. I wanted to fetch the data regardless of posting new data to database. Check my solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6ni1pg

Comment: Hi, sorry I could not access the https://budget-dfc78.firebaseio.com/posts.json any more. Error 401 was returned.